# Appending div with load() on an icon click to many siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my dynamically added editors. I want to be able to append div .fonts-container on click on icon  .icon-size, but when the div has been already loaded it can be hidden by clicking again on the same icon, and by gettig css: display:none.
Then when icon is clicked again the div is not loaded again, it is just changing css to display: block.

My JS code works like that, but it is buggy when I have more then 1 .editor. F.e. when I am changing font on title1, and than I want to change font on title2 is is not loading new div .fonts-container by title2, instead .fonts-container is showing up on title1 by changing css to display:block.

How can I make this JS works on more than one div .editor

```
<div class="editor ui-resizable ui-draggable">
   <h2 class="text2" style="font-size: 3em;">Title1</h2>
   <img class="icon-font" src="/assets/font_size2.png" style="z-index: 2;">
   <img class="icon-size" src="/assets/font_size2.png" style="z-index: 2;">
   <div class="fonts-container" style="display: none;">
</div>

<div class="editor ui-resizable ui-draggable">
   <h2 class="text2" style="font-size: 3em;">Title2</h2>
   <img class="icon-font" src="/assets/font_size2.png" style="z-index: 2;">
   <img class="icon-size" src="">
   <div class="fonts-container" style="display: none;">
</div>

<div class="editor ui-resizable ui-draggable">
   <h2 class="text2" style="font-size: 3em;">Title3</h2>
   <img class="icon-font" src="/assets/font_size2.png" style="z-index: 2;">
   <img class="icon-size" src="">
   <div class="fonts-container" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

here is my buggy js:

```
$(document).on('click', '.icon-size', function() { 
  $('.fonts-size-container').hide().hide();
  if ( !$(this).hasClass("active") ) {
      $(this).addClass("active");
         if ( !$(".fonts-container").hasClass("active")) {
            $(this).parent().append("<div class='fonts-container'></div>");
            $(".fonts-container").load("/fonts.html", null,
            function (responseText, status, response) {});
            $(".fonts-container").addClass("active");
        } else {
          $('.fonts-container').css("display" , "block");
        }
    } else {
       $('.fonts-container').hide("slow");
       $(this).removeClass("active");
    } 
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you use `$(".fonts-container")` it returns *all* the DIVs with that class, not just the one associated with the image you clicked on. You need to find that element using a DOM traversal function.

```
$(document).on('click', '.icon-size', function() { 
    $('.fonts-size-container').hide();
    var $this_container = $(this).next(".fonts-container");
    if ( !$(this).hasClass("active") ) {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        if ( !$this_container.hasClass("active")) {
            $(this).parent().append("<div class='fonts-container'></div>");
            $this_container.load("/fonts.html", null,
                                       function (responseText, status, response) {});
            $this_container.addClass("active");
        } else {
            $this_container.css("display" , "block");
        }
    } else {
        $this_container.hide("slow");
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    } 
});
```